# postgresql partitioning master table duplicate entries

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, database-partitioning

I ve created a simple partitioning structure as given below:

**Master table**

```
CREATE TABLE parent_table
(
  id_n numeric(19,0) NOT NULL,
  name_v character varying(255),
  location_n numeric(19,0),
  CONSTRAINT parent_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_n )
)
```

**Child tables**

```
CREATE TABLE child_table_location_1
(
-- Inherited from table parent_table:  id_n numeric(19,0) NOT NULL,
-- Inherited from table parent_table:  name_v character varying(255),
-- Inherited from table parent_table:  location_n numeric(19,0),
  CONSTRAINT child_table_location_1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_n ),
  CONSTRAINT child_table_location_1_location_n_check CHECK (location_n = 1::numeric)
)INHERITS (parent_table)

CREATE TABLE child_table_location_2
(
-- Inherited from table parent_table:  id_n numeric(19,0) NOT NULL,
-- Inherited from table parent_table:  name_v character varying(255),
-- Inherited from table parent_table:  location_n numeric(19,0),
  CONSTRAINT child_table_location_2_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_n ),
  CONSTRAINT child_table_location_2_location_n_check CHECK (location_n = 2::numeric)
)INHERITS (parent_table)
```

**Trigger**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PARTITION_INSERTION_TRIGGER()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO '|| QUOTE_IDENT('child_table_location_'||NEW.LOCATION_N)||' SELECT ($1).*' USING NEW;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER INSERT_INTO_PARTITION_TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT ON PARENT_TABLE FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE PARTITION_INSERTION_TRIGGER();
```

I create the trigger such that based on the location field, the data gets populated in respective child tables.

Now I ve the below insert scripts:

```
INSERT INTO parent_table(id_n, name_v, location_n) VALUES (1, 'aaa', 1);
INSERT INTO parent_table(id_n, name_v, location_n) VALUES (2, 'bbb', 2);
INSERT INTO parent_table(id_n, name_v, location_n) VALUES (3, 'ccc', 1);
INSERT INTO parent_table(id_n, name_v, location_n) VALUES (4, 'ddd', 2);
INSERT INTO parent_table(id_n, name_v, location_n) VALUES (5, 'eee', 1);
INSERT INTO parent_table(id_n, name_v, location_n) VALUES (6, 'fff', 2);
```

When I select from individual tables:

**Child Table 1**

```
id_n| name_v| location_n
1|"aaa"|1
3|"ccc"|1
5|"eee"|1
```

**Child Table 2**

```
id_n| name_v| location_n
2|"bbb"|2
4|"ddd"|2
6|"fff"|2
```

But when I query on the master table:

**Parent table**

```
id_n|name_v|location_n
1|"aaa"|1
1|"aaa"|1
2|"bbb"|2
2|"bbb"|2
3|"ccc"|1
3|"ccc"|1
4|"ddd"|2
4|"ddd"|2
5|"eee"|1
5|"eee"|1
6|"fff"|2
6|"fff"|2
```

I get duplicate entries from the parent_table even after having the primary key constraint on the id field.

Why it is happening and what changes should I make on my design.

Awaiting quick response.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi all, solved by modifying the PARTITION_INSERTION_TRIGGER function.
Returned NULL instead of returning NEW :)

Answer (score -1):

Returning NULL is not the clean way.

The elegant solution is to have the trigger "INSTEAD OF"

See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: `instead of` only works on views and so isn't applicable when using table partitioning